# Chemfig: length and angle of bonds

Tags: chemfig

I've just tried using `chemfig` for the first time to try and recreate a figure (below).
[image]

I had a quick look through the manual so see if there was an example that I could adapt to my needs, and this is what I've managed code-wise and in terms of output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{P(=[2]O)(-[7]C_{5}H_{11})(-[5]C_{5}H_{11}O)(-[3]C_{5}H_{11}O)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now whilst, this looks to be correct, I think that the bond lengths are a little bit too long, and also the angles of the bonds are too steep.  How would I go about changing this?  Also, the method that I've used to set the angles of the bonds doesn't seem to be that flexible, as I only seem to be able to set the bonds at 45 degree intervals, is there another way to do this where I can specify custom angles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{P(=[2,0.7]O)(-[:-30,0.8]C_{5}H_{11})(-[:150,0.8]C_{5}H_{11}O)(-[:210,0.8]C_{5}H_{11}O)}
\end{document}
```

To specify an angle you have to use the notation `[:<angle>]`, while to specify a custom length for the bonds you have to use `[,<length>]`, so for example, if you want something at 150° and with a bond length of 0.8 you have to use `[:150,0.8]`